# Include primary key on schema information in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, primary-key

I have this query:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_name='my_table';
```

It's output looks something like:

```
              column_name               |    data_type     | character_maximum_length 
----------------------------------------+------------------+--------------------------
 key                                    | integer          |                         
 created_date_key                       | integer          |                         
 call_scheduled_date_key                | integer          |                         
 call_completed_date_key                | integer          |                         
 enroll_date_key                        | integer          |                         
 syllabus_request_date_fst_key          | integer          |                         
 info_session_registration_date_fst_key | integer          |
```

I would like to have two more columns, one called "primary_key" and another called "foreign_key" that contain boolean values.

Is this possible?

Comment: `I would like to have two more columns, one called "primary_key" and another called "foreign_key" that contain boolean values.` That would allow only two non-constrained values for your PK and your FK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this information from these two views: `key_column_usage` and `referential_constraints`. The `key_column_usage` view lists all key columns: primary and foreign. To distinguish between the two use the `referential_constraints` view that tells you if the constraint is the  referential (foreign key) constraint:

```
SELECT c.column_name, c.data_type, c.character_maximum_length,
CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.constraint_column_usage k WHERE c.table_name = k.table_name and k.column_name = c.column_name) 
     THEN true ELSE false END as primary_key, 
CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.key_column_usage k WHERE c.table_name = k.table_name and k.column_name = c.column_name) AND 
          EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.referential_constraints f INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.key_column_usage k ON k.constraint_name = f.constraint_name WHERE k.column_name = c.column_name) 
     THEN true ELSE false END as foreign_key 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c 
WHERE c.table_name='my_table';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the system catalog [`pg_constraint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html) to get the desired data. Example:

```
create table my_table(
    id serial primary key, 
    fid int references my_other_table(id), 
    str varchar(10));

select 
    column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length, 
    bool_or(contype is not distinct from 'p') as primary_key, 
    bool_or(contype is not distinct from 'f') as foreign_key
from information_schema.columns
left join pg_constraint 
    on conrelid = table_name::regclass and ordinal_position = any(conkey)
where table_name='my_table'
group by 1, 2, 3;

 column_name |     data_type     | character_maximum_length | primary_key | foreign_key 
-------------+-------------------+--------------------------+-------------+-------------
 id          | integer           |                          | t           | f
 fid         | integer           |                          | f           | t
 str         | character varying |                       10 | f           | f
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Your solution does not support a situation when the column is both a primary key and at the same time refers to a foreign table. Also, it is duplicating for some reasons if the foreign key belongs to more than one table.